# Converter número em horas em python

Tags: python, pandas

Como converter um número 1234 que representa a houras para uma string com formato hora ex. 12:34 em python?

Comment: Como converter 5 em 00:05?

Comment: E se for 1265? Não tem como virar 12:65.

Comment: Esse número representa um horário ou uma quantidade de horas/minutos?

Answer (score 0):

Fiz da seguinte forma para situações em que o número de input seja por exemplo 5

```
 x_fill = str(x).zfill(4)
result = str(x_fill)[:2]+':'+str(x_fill)[2:]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def horas(number):
    return str(number)[:2]+':'+str(number)[2:]

horas(1234)
```

Output: `'12:34'`